# Installation of gstreamer bad plugins and opencv3.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 arm64

Tags: installation, ubuntu-16.04, gstreamer, nvidia, opencv3.0

I have been working on some video playing/streaming pipelines for Computer Vision work on Nvidia Jetson TX2. It had Ubuntu 16.04 with latest Jetpack.

I have already installed opencv 3.3 and to test some of the pipelines, with .MP$ video files, I need h264parse plugin which is a part of gst-bad-plugins. However, when I try to install it using apt-get, it shows that following packages will be installed:

```
freepats gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers
libbs2b0 libde265-0 libflite1 libfluidsynth1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
libmimic0 libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmms0 libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 libmplex2-2.1-0
libofa0 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopencv-calib3d2.4v5
libopencv-contrib2.4v5 libopencv-core2.4v5 libopencv-features2d2.4v5
libopencv-flann2.4v5 libopencv-highgui2.4v5 libopencv-imgproc2.4v5
libopencv-legacy2.4v5 libopencv-ml2.4v5 libopencv-objdetect2.4v5
libopencv-video2.4v5 libsoundtouch1 libspandsp2 libsrtp0 libvo-aacenc0
libvo-amrwbenc0 libwildmidi-config libwildmidi1 libzbar0
```

Here it tries to install an older version of opencv and this really messes up with my current opencv (v3.3) install.

Does anyone have any idea on how should I overcome this problem. I would not want the option to just ignore all the dependencies. But somehow, if it detects the installed opencv version, that would be awesome.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Jetson Tx1 , and have problem installing opencv 3.3 in virtual environment onto it due to space issues. I tried to compile the build file from external sd card and make from there. Then Sym-link (cv2.so) file to appropriate path. Can you tell me how you were able to install opencv3.3 ??

Comment: I did not have any memory problems. I did not even install it in a virtual environment. Sorry.

Comment: I built OpenCV 3.4.1 from sources using the instructions I found here: https://jkjung-avt.github.io/opencv3-on-tx2/